# Append Application (Android / Iphone / Windows) version in HTTP Request?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, http, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET server with client application available in Android,Iphone and Windows. I want to append the application version**(for example 2.1.2 **my application version**)** in HTTP request headers. Which header should I use for this? BTW, I know about User-Agent.I am asking to include **my specific application version**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-Agent is the correct place to add this information.  You can attach multiple product/version combinations into a user-agent header.  Your client application is acting as a type of user agent in this case and that is the most appropriate place to add this information.  From the HTTP spec

> The field can contain multiple product tokens (section 3.8) and
>   comments identifying the agent and any subproducts which form a
>   significant part of the user agent.

e.g.

```
User-Agent : foo/1.0 foobar/0.9 foobazbar/2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for an android client.

**First you need to get the version from your app**. Here is an exemple with the version name (you can also recover the version code if needed).

```
String vName = null;
try{     
    vName = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),0).versionName;   
} 
catch(NameNotFoundException e){   
}
```

**Then just add your version to http header** when you request your server from the client app.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://myserver.com/postrequest");
if(vName != null){
    httppost.addHeader("ClientAppVersion", vName);
}
...
```